# How does this `cat` command to txt script file work?

Tags: command-line, cat, xargs

Suppose we have a txt file `file.txt` with each line is a python script e.g. 

`python a1.py
python a2.py
python a3.py`

What does the following command is really doing ?

`cat file.txt | xargs -n 1 -P $NUM_CPUS bash -c`

Comment: this forum is not the best place to ask if this is a homework....first step, read `man xargs`....then read `man bash` for the `-c` flag...

Answer (score 1):

Elucidation:

```
cat file.txt | xargs -n 1 -P $NUM_CPUS bash -c
```

- `cat file.txt` - concatenate the file `file.txt` contents passed to next program in pipeline
- `xargs -n 1` - accept 1 argument from the STDIN(previous command output) at a time
- `-P $NUM_CPUS` - run up to `$NUM_CPUS` processes at a time (one input line for each process invocation)
- `bash -c` - the command executed with current argument

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$NUM_CPUS` contains an integer, then the command will start at most that many parallel non-interactive `bash` shells (that's what `-P` does). Each shell will run one line from the input file (due to `-n 1`).

The `cat` command is not needed:

```
xargs -n 1 -P "$NUM_CPUS" bash -c <file.txt
```